# Dropdown does not appear

Tags: android, android-spinner

[enter image description here]  [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J1eqc.png)[enter image description here]  [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S2VYU.png)[enter image description here][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qpqOH.png)I have been trying to make a dropdown box but I am not able to see the dropdown. Only the first option appears. The first option appears and then the app closes. I am new to Android Please help. here is the main xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dip"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
        android:text="Category:"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"/>

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:prompt="@string/spinner_title"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

and the main activity as this

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnItemSelectedListener{
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);

    // Spinner click listener
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    List<String> categories = new ArrayList<String>();
    categories.add("Auto");
    categories.add("BUI");
 ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, categories);
    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
}
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    // On selecting a spinner item
    String item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

    // Showing selected spinner item
    Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "Selected: " + item, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

}
```

My gradle file

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


android {
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.admin.mydropdowns"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

}


  dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

 }
```

here is my logcat

```
11-03 10:29:47.260 3721-3721/? I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)

11-03 10:29:47.260 3721-3721/? W/art: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86

11-03 10:29:47.404 3721-3721/com.example.admin.mydropdowns W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.admin.mydropdowns-2/lib/x86

 11-03 10:29:47.428 3721-3721/com.example.admin.mydropdowns W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable


   [ 11-03 10:29:47.467  1525: 1573 D/         ]

HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x90ccdf40, tid 1573

11-03 10:29:47.600 3721-3741/com.example.admin.mydropdowns I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4

11-03 10:29:47.600 3721-3741/com.example.admin.mydropdowns D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1


11-03 10:29:47.601 3721-3741/com.example.admin.mydropdowns W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...

11-03 10:29:47.601 3721-3741/com.example.admin.mydropdowns D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 0

11-03 10:30:00.491 3721-3741/com.example.admin.mydropdowns E/OpenGLRenderer: GL error: 0x506

 11-03 10:30:00.492 3721-3741/com.example.admin.mydropdowns A/OpenGLRenderer: GL errors! frameworks/base/libs/hwui/renderthread/CanvasContext.cpp:550

 11-03 10:30:00.492 3721-3741/com.example.admin.mydropdowns A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 3741 (RenderThread)


    [ 11-03 10:30:00.492  1222: 1222 W/         ]
                                                               debuggerd: handling request: pid=3721 uid=10076 gid=10076 tid=3741
```

Comment: Post ur error Log

Comment: post your error log

Comment: There is no error!! it just closes and no dropdown is visible.

Comment: I have tried your code in my project and it worked fine without any issue. Try to give some value to the spinner_title in strings.xml if not provided.

Comment: implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener not OnItemSelectedListener

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:text="Category:"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"/>

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

Try changing ur xml file to this 
Then change code of your java file to this:
Because you are not giving right context when you show toast, u need to give context of activity in which u r in instead of adapterview.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);

    List<String> categories = new ArrayList<String>();
    categories.add("Auto");
    categories.add("BUI");
 ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, categories);
    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> dataAdapter, View v, int position, long id)
            {
               String item = dataAdapter.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

               // Showing selected spinner item
               Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Selected: " + item, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0)
            {

            }
        });
}

}
```

It worked here is the output:
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: It will work for you mate. Dont forget to mark it answer as this post will help others too. If it works let me know I will tell you about the reason that what you were doing wrong. First when you are showing toast u were giving wrong context you dont have to give it context of adapterview you have to give it context of activity in which you are in. Also fill_parent is depricated so use wrap_content instead.

Comment: @M. Saad its showing an unresolved symbol getContext()

Comment: Instead of getContext(), use MainActivity.this

Comment: @M.Saad Lakhan Please  mention the changes  clearly  thank you.

Comment: yes @DileepPerla you are right , buddy follow dileep what he said

Comment: @Ajeetyadav Bro I mentioned in comment section moreover in detail too

Comment: Let me know if it works or if there are errors do upgrade me mate.

Comment: @M.SaadLakhan I tried this but Ill add error's snapshot here so that you can have a look.

Comment: Oo mate remove implements onSelectedItemListenerfromtop

Comment: @M.SaadLakhan I have already done that please check. Thanks all for helping me out.

Comment: check edited answer I updated, Sorry I forgot to check that line of your code

Comment: If yes is the case dont forget to mark my post as answer please

Comment: @M.SaadLakhan those errors are gone but the previous error persists. I have put a snapshot of  how it looks.

Comment: What happened exactly when u run app, screen popups when u click down arrow of dropdown is it shows something? are u able to click ? when ur app crash ? Try to explain me the whole scenario mate

Comment: When I run the app the app appears and the line Selected: Auto appears and if I click on dropdown it closes.

Comment: if any errors in code show me on which line there are errors

Comment: ok mate show me the log... Its strange btw anyhow show me ur log I will make it work for you :)

Comment: @M.SaadLakhan thanks a lot. I hope you dont mind but what is log?? I am completely new to programming

Comment: Its ok mate no problem the screenshot u showed me the bottom right window titles Event log is basically ur log run this app and show me what prints over there

Comment: 11/2/2017
12:24 PM Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]

12:24 PM Gradle build finished in 1s 220ms

Comment: Buddy is the code given above is your complete code ?

Comment: Yes I think so I have not changed anything anywhere else

Comment: <resources>
    <string name="app_name">My Dropdowns</string>

</resources>  strings.xml

Comment: Bro I just made a project of it it worked absolutely fine I will attach screenshots

Comment: Oh is it ! What is the problem then will you be able to figure out if I send you the whole project. I am clueless of what to do?

Comment: Bro I dont know whats going wrong I added screenshots edited my answer look there everything is working fine mate. Ok if it works for you mark my post as answer. I dont know whats the matter it should work :/

Comment: implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener not OnItemSelectedListener

Comment: I wrote the code completely what I sent to you.It worked

Comment: @Ajeetyadav Bro its working I tested it on my machine its totally working there is no issue at all.

Comment: Thanks a lot @M.SaadLakhan this should work out but I am not able to make it happen at all. Tried connecting it to a database also but even that showed errors. Anyways thanks ill try to figure it out.

Comment: Your welcome hope you will make it work soon buddy :)

Comment: @M.SaadLakhan I tried using a debugger and found that the adapter is NULL any ideas what could be the reason? i have added a screen shot above. Again thanks.

Comment: @M.SaadLakhan it worked after a long time I applied your  code but I am still not able to understand the error though. Anyways thanks a lot.

Comment: @M.SaadLakhan i have added logcat and I also f ind that the app works once in a while then it crashes.

Comment: Bro this is very strange I am also not sure what is happening wrong in your case

Comment: @M.SaadLakhan then the logcat is not helping is it?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the line :

```
android:prompt="@string/spinner_title"
```

from the Layout file

Other than this will work absolutely fine in this snippet.

Then make your arraylist as

```
List<String> categories = new ArrayList<String>(); 
categories.add("Select Category"); 
categories.add("Auto"); 
categories.add("BUI");
```

and then handle the condition by index position as you want like

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
if (position ==0){
 // Showing the prompt
    Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "Please select category", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}else{
 // On selecting a spinner item
 String item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

 // Showing selected spinner item
 Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "Selected: " + item, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}}
```

Comment: I tried this but it then selects the first option and shows that AUTO Selected.

Comment: then make your arraylist as 

List<String> categories = new ArrayList<String>();
  categories.add("Select Category");   
  categories.add("Auto");
  categories.add("BUI");

Comment: hope your problem will solve by this happy coding :)

Comment: @Ajeetyadav buddy he is doing that right the context he was providing there was wrong

Comment: @ M.Saad Lakhan Ok bro i hope he got his problem solved  :)

Comment: once clean the project and build again

Comment: i have tested your code myself it is working fine without anyproblem

Comment: Now got it  implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener not  OnItemSelectedListener.